# Show categories and subcategories using observer in phtml

Tags: php, json, magento

I have setup magento project. i want to fetch categories and sub categories using observer in json format. This info i want to call in phtml and show in frontend.

Also, when i create a category and sub category, observer get automatically update with json data. this json data should pass to pthml file.

how can we implement this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code,you will get this list of all categories and subcategories in JSON format.

```
     function getCategoryTree($recursionLevel, $storeId = 1)
     {
        $parent = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();    
        $tree = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_tree');

        $nodes = $tree->loadNode($parent)
                      ->loadChildren($recursionLevel)
                      ->getChildren();
        $tree->addCollectionData(null, false, $parent);

        $categoryTreeData = array();

        foreach ($nodes as $node)
        {
          $categoryTreeData[$node->getData('entity_id')] = getNodeChildrenData($node);
        }

        return $categoryTreeData;
      }

     function getNodeChildrenData(Varien_Data_Tree_Node $node)
     {
        $data = array(
        'title' => $node->getData('name'),
        'url'   => $node->getData('url_key'),
        );

        foreach ($node->getChildren() as $childNode)
        {
            if (!array_key_exists('children', $data))
            {
                $data['children'] = array();
            }

            $data['children'][$childNode->getData('entity_id')] = getNodeChildrenData($childNode);
        }

        return $data;
    }

    print_r(json_encode(getCategoryTree(3)));
```